# ¿Cómo puedo asignar lo que tiene fecha al datepicker #fechamax en la opción minDate?

Tags: javascript

```js
    $( function() {
      $("#fechamin").datepicker();
      $("#fechamax").datepicker();
    
      $("#fechamin").on("change", function() {
        var fecha = $("#fechamin").datepicker("getDate");
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1); 
        $("#fechamax").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    
    <input type="text" id="fechamin" />
    <input type="text" id="fechamax" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien lo que quieres es que en el `datepicker` `fechamax` se asigne el `mindate` con la fecha seleccionada en `fechamin`.

Simplemente llamando a  `$("#fechamax").datepicker( "option", "minDate", fecha);` o encadenando la llamada a la que ya tienes (como he hecho en el ejemplo) lo tendrías.

```js
    $( function() {
      $("#fechamin").datepicker();
      $("#fechamax").datepicker();
    
      $("#fechamin").on("change", function() {
        var fecha = $("#fechamin").datepicker("getDate");
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1); 
        $("#fechamax").datepicker("setDate", fecha).datepicker( "option", "minDate", fecha);
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    
    <input type="text" id="fechamin" />
    <input type="text" id="fechamax" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso era lo que ocupaba..

Comment: @Andres si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, considera marcarla como aceptada (el check que está a la izquierda de la pregunta) y votarla positivamente (la flecha hacia arriba). Un saludo